# Message box appearing twice when code is ran

Tags: excel, vba

For some reason the message box appearing twice when the code is ran. I'm not sure where its looping thru. I edited to add new1 click sub. Thanks for the help. This only if they click on yes. If they click no it only shows up once.

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()

    Me.SpinButton1.Min = 1
    Me.SpinButton1.Max = Worksheets("Job Tracking").Range("D1")
       
    Worksheets("Job Tracking").Range("B1").Value = SpinButton1.Value

    Call New1_Click
        
    If Worksheets("Job Tracking").Range("I4") > 0 Then
        Call MsgBoxYesNo
        Worksheets("Job Tracking").Range("I4") = ""
    End If
        
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub MsgBoxYesNo()
    Dim answerY As Integer
    
    answerY = MsgBox("Continue From This Job?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Yes or No")
    
    If answerY = vbYes Then
        Me.SpinButton1.Value = Worksheets("Job Tracking").Range("G1").Value
        Worksheets("Job Tracking").Range("I4") = ""
        
    Else
        Worksheets("Job Tracking").Range("I4") = ""
        Call New1_Click
    End If
    
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub New1_Click()
    blnNew = True
        TextBox1.Text = Worksheets("Job Tracking").Range("B3")
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        TextBox3.Text = Now()
        Me.cmdSave.Top = 38
        Me.cmdClose.Left = 132
        Me.Search.Left = 192
        TextBox22.Text = Range("E14").Value
        
    If Worksheets("Job Tracking").Range("C5") = "" Then
        
        GoTo Fix1
        
    End If
        
        TextBox12.Value = Val(Worksheets("Job Tracking").Range("H14")) / Val(TextBox5.Text)
        TextBox23.Value = Worksheets("Job Tracking").Range("H14")
Fix1:
  On Error Resume Next
    
        cmdClose.Enabled = True
        cmdSave.Enabled = True
   
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens in `New1_Click`

Comment: @bejesus19 - add that to your post under current code ^ hard to read in comments lol. I just edited your question. You can add line breaks with '---'. To indent your code just paste it all, highlight and hit CTRL + K

Comment: Just step through your code using F8 to see what is causing the msgbox to appear twice. You may need to add break points. That is going to be the best way to follow and find out where, if at all, your code is looping

Comment: @bejesus19 What object type is _SpinButton1_? Maybe the _change_ event is triggert on press and release.

Comment: edited to show "New1_Click" also a little more details

Comment: When you answer Yes this line of code fires:  `Me.SpinButton1.Value = Worksheets("Job Tracking").Range("G1").Value`.  That's changing the spin button value and causing `SpinButton1_Change()` event to fire again.  Try disabling events at the start of the change event and reenable at the end.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook is right ...  when the user answers `vbYes` to the message box then `SpinButton1_Change()` is called immediately (i.e. before the subsequent line that sets the value of cell "I4" to an empty string). An alternative solution is to swap the two lines around (ie the line that sets the value of `SpinButton1` and the line that sets cell "I4" to an empty string ... or, better, as you set cell "I4" to an empty string whether the user replies `vbYes` or not, set cell "I4" to an empty string before testing whether `answerY = vbYes`)

Comment: @JohnM.... thevbahelp.com Not looked at your site before.  I'll have to have a browse :)

Comment: I removed the the whole line with Range("I4") = "" in it. Still the same thing. @DarrenBartrup-Cook I'm not sure how to disable and the re-able the event change

Comment: Add `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the start and `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end.  If your code errors out before reaching the end make sure you open the immediate window and enter `Application.EnableEvents = True`

Comment: Thats what i thought (lol) but it didnt work. --- If Worksheets("Job Tracking").Range("I4") > 0 Then
    
                Application.EnableEvents = False
        Call MsgBoxYesNo
                Application.EnableEvents = True